# Why is one of the transistors in ROM sense amplifier twice the width of the one opposite of him?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, eeprom, operational-amplifier, rom

[image]

The picture is of Sense Amp design of ROM component in which a 'dummy' bit line is used to imitate the current so that the proper information can be derived from the memory cell by comparing the currents.

I would like to know why does the right transistor have a width of 2Wx and the one on the left Wx?

Comment: A 2Wx transistor is exactly the same as placing **two** Wx transistors **in parallel**. Now, if we apply a voltage across a Wx transistor, a current would flow. How much current would flow when the same voltage is applied to a 2Wx transistor? It is unclear from the schematic why those current relation would be needed as the schematic is incomplete and unclear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the one on the right sees two signals a "0" (\$I_0\$) 
and a "1" (\$I_1\$)
the one on the left sees one signal \$I_m\$ a '0' or a 'i'

the compartor computes \$ I_m > ( I_0 + I_1 ) / 2 \$

To get the `/2` it needs to be twice as wide on other side